# Need a an htaccess substution recomendation

Tags: .htaccess

Want a simple htaccess to redirect html root filename to a sub-directory.

[www.xyz.com/About****.php](http://www.xyz.com/About****.php)  where **** is arbitrary. The words "About" and ".php" are fixed

convert to [www.xyz.com/coach/articles/About****.php](http://www.xyz.com/coach/articles/About****.php)

Haven't  used regular expressions and htaccess for many years. Relearning curve is time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

This will redirect every URL that matches `About****.php` to `coach/articles/About****.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^About(.*).php$ coach/articles/About$1.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Many thanks. My memory taint what it use to be

Comment: Doesn't work. Here is test result https://www.ridersite.org/AboutHow.pdf >RewriteRule ^About(.*)\.php$ coach/articles/About$1.php [L,R=301]

This rule was not met.

Comment: You said: `"About" and ".php" are fixed` -> The rule `^About(.*).php$`, of course, it doesn't match: `AboutHow.pdf`. It matches `AboutHow.php` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Full example:
https://riderxxx.org/About_How_To_Select_Your_Performance_Training_Courses.pdf

Result:
https://riderxxx.org/Coach/Articles_pdf/About_How_To_Select_Your_Performance_Training_Courses.pdf

The article is in /Coach/Articles_pdf/ But, users are having trouble dealing with the full URL

Comment: You should edit your post if you want to add more details, this is an answer section. Also, I replied to you about your example with AboutHow.pdf